# Implementing Real-Time Message Count for Personal Message System using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am working on creating a Personal Message System for my website. For this, I would like to display and update the number of new messages in each chat in real-time, similar to the red "box" shown in the following screenshot: [image: Image with a Message-Counter]

At the moment, the message count is not written in the div provided, and I'm not sure why.

Here is the relevant HTML code:

```
<div class="chat_body"> 
    <a href="index.php?section=pn&mode=loadConversation&ConversationID=<?php echo $conversation['id']; ?>">
        <div class="user" id='<?php echo $i ?>' data-user-id='<?php echo $user_id?>' data-conv-id='<?php echo $conversation['id'] ?>'>
            // Displaying the name, etc...
        <?php                   
            echo "<div class='rightCountUnreadMessages'>";
                /* Showing the actual counter */
                echo '<div class="badge" id="badge-'.$i.'"></div>';
            echo "</div>";
        ?>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

jQuery function, that should determine the number of new messages every 500ms:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //jQuery(setInterval(function() {
        friends_count = document.getElementsByClassName("user").length;
        for(var i=1; i < friends_count+1; i++) {
            el = document.getElementById(i);
            conv_id = el.getAttribute("data-conv-id");
            user_id = el.getAttribute("data-user-id");
            test = i;

            jQuery.post('./Bauteile/Accounts/loadCounts/loadPNCount.php', {user_id_loadPN: user_id, conv_id: conv_id}, function(result){
                console.log(result);
                if(result > 99) result = "99+";

                if(result > 0 || result == "99+") {
                    document.getElementById("badge-"+test).innerHTML = result;
                }
            })
        }
    //}, 500));
});
```

And in the requested document in Javascript has the following content:

```
<?php
    $conv_id = $_POST['conv_id'];
    $from_id = $_POST['user_id_loadPN'];

    echo (int)mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `messages` WHERE `group_id` = $chat_id AND `from_id` = $from_id AND `read_on` is NULL"), 0);
?>
```

Comment: Does your JQuery post function return something ? In this line : console.log(result);

Comment: Yes, 3 times 0. This is not the right number, but I think, that its because of the for-loop connected with the jQuery.Post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have something asynchronous in your loop. To solve this problem you need a closure. You need to wrap the content of the for loop in a function that takes i as a parameter, then call the function in the loop.
So try something like this :

```
function doClosure(i) {
    var el = document.getElementById(i),
        conv_id = el.getAttribute("data-conv-id"),
        user_id = el.getAttribute("data-user-id"),
        test = i;

    jQuery.post('./Bauteile/Accounts/loadCounts/loadPNCount.php', {user_id_loadPN: user_id, conv_id: conv_id}, function(result){
        console.log(result);
        console.log(test);

        if(result > 99) {
            result = "99+";
        }

        if(result > 0 || result == "99+") {
            document.getElementById("badge-"+test).innerHTML = result;
        }
    });
}

for (var i = 1; i < document.getElementsByClassName("user").length+1; i++) {
    doClosure(i);
}
```

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you very much! *-* You helped me alot! :))

Comment: But then my basic idea, that the jQuery and the forloop doesn't work properly was right, but I never thought, that this is so confused... :P

Comment: You're welcome @Gykonik. To explain simply, your JQuery post request doesn't go at the same speed as your for loop. So she doesn't take the right data. This is why you need a closure.

Answer (score 0):

**Addition to my post:**

I replaced

```
jQuery.post('./Bauteile/Accounts/loadCounts/loadPNCount.php', {user_id_loadPN: user_id, conv_id: conv_id}, function(result){
```

with

```
console.log(user_id + " " + i);     
jQuery.post('./Bauteile/Accounts/loadCounts/loadPNCount.php', {user_id_loadPN: user_id, conv_id: conv_id}, function(result){
    console.log(result + " " + i);
```

for debugging...

The console output was:

- 21 1   line: 254 (= first console.log in this example)
- 26 2   line: 254
- 27 3   line: 254
- 26 4   line: 256 (= sec. console.log in this example)
- 27 4   line: 256
- 21 4   line: 256

So, as i suspected the For-loop and the jQuery function doesn't work together very well...